# for loop ignores some elements of my list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove items from a list while iterating in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python)

I want to remove all the dates in a list which are later than a given date.  I can't see why my method only removes some items of the list. Here's what I've got:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import os

list_dates = [datetime.date(2012,1,3), datetime.date(2012,1,1), datetime.date(2012,1,5), datetime.date(2013,1,3), datetime.date(2013,1,1)]

for item in list_dates:
    if item > datetime.date(2012,1,1):
        list_dates.remove(item)

print list_dates
```

returns

```
[datetime.date(2012, 1, 1), datetime.date(2013, 1, 3)]
```

Comment: It's probably because you're modifying the list as you traverse it.

Comment: You cannot iterate through a list and simultaneously remove items from it.

Comment: Oh, that's a shame... Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @GWW: The problem is, you *can* - it just doesn't work and is rarely useful.

Comment: @delnan: I suppose that's a better phrasing

Comment: Agreeing with @delnan.  This kind of thing really should throw a syntax error.  Actually, I thought it *did*, but maybe I'm thinking of Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

James and GWW are right, you cant modify the list while you are iterating through the same. Instead copy the items which you want to keep to a new list.

```
list_dates = [datetime.date(2012,1,3), datetime.date(2012,1,1), datetime.date(2012,1,5), datetime.date(2013,1,3), datetime.date(2013,1,1)]        

for item in list_dates:
            if item < datetime.date(2012,1,1):
                new_list_dates.add(item); // move this item (which you want to keep) to a new list.

    print new_list_dates
```

Comment: You could also use a list comprehension for this (if you see the question I marked this as a duplicate of)

Answer (score 0):

Or modify in place like this:

```
import datetime

list_dates = [datetime.date(2012,1,3), datetime.date(2012,1,1), datetime.date(2012,1,5), datetime.date(2013,1,3), datetime.date(2013,1,1)]

for i in range(len(list_dates) - 1, -1, -1):
    item = list_dates[i]
    if item > datetime.date(2012,1,1):
        del list_dates[i]

print list_dates
```

or

```
import datetime


list_dates = [datetime.date(2012,1,3), datetime.date(2012,1,1), datetime.date(2012,1,5), datetime.date(2013,1,3), datetime.date(2013,1,1)]

i = 0
while i < len(list_dates):
    item = list_dates[i]
    if item > datetime.date(2012,1,1):
        del list_dates[i]
    else:
        i += 1

print list_dates
```